# PBXCp error ..... is longer than filepath buffer size (1025)

Tags: ios

Has anybody ever faced this issue:
`PBXCp error ..... is longer than filepath buffer size (1025)`

Answer (score 38):

Yes, I got the same problem.

Inside Build Phases-> "Copy Bundle Resources" section, a folder was nested with the project folder again (it means duplicating files).

So xcode is trying to recursively build the product, so it can add the product itself recursively as a resource for itself.

Remove that product( duplicate folder ) itself from "Copy Bundle Resources" section.
This method solved the problem for me.

Comment: You get the same problem if your target is mysteriously in the Copy Bundle Resources section. I deleted it and it all works now.

Comment: @Tim deleting target from the "Copy Bundle Resource Section" solved my problem, thanks

Comment: thanks man this is harder issue we dont even understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying everything for the past week. Followed exactly as listed and BAM!! its building again! Thanks again for your time.

Comment: had the same issue was working on it for hours! deleting the target *.app  fixed the issues. probably from a git merge.

Answer (score 23):

go to xcode and select Runner.app in Products folder. Then uncheck the Target Membership checkbox. This alone resolved my issue. The way veeresh kumbar mentioned above also will solve the problem it is just manual way to do so.

Comment: Man I spend whole day fixing this error. Thanks alot man!

Comment: You are god. You saved my day.

Comment: bravo. I am new to ios. I was struggling for around a wk. you made my day.

Comment: it solved my error, but I don't understand

Comment: This worked for me as well, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have duplicated the folder inside the same folder which might have duplicated the files. This was the case for me and trashing out duplicated folder fixed the issue.