# Can't build react-native app due to errant recursive path issue

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have a project that i have built in react-native for IOS and Android. Recently I cleared excess simulator files to free up space on my mac. That gave me issues as far as running my app through xcode and the xcode cli with metro.

I figured perhaps I had deleted too much, so I reinstalled xcode. Since reinstalling xcode, (multiple times I might add) i have had a recurring issue with the build process creating a recursive .app file.

Error when building from xcode app:

```
CpResource /Users/lukearthur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-fxjyxyudankxxjejsdezxolszzhy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile.app/mobile.app /Users/lukearthur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-fxjyxyudankxxjejsdezxolszzhy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile.app (in target 'mobile' from project 'mobile')
    cd /Users/lukearthur/Documents/NarthurWork/taskratchet-mobile/ios
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/lukearthur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-fxjyxyudankxxjejsdezxolszzhy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile.app /Users/lukearthur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-fxjyxyudankxxjejsdezxolszzhy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile.app

error: '/Users/lukearthur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-fxjyxyudankxxjejsdezxolszzhy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/mobile.app/Frameworks' is longer than filepath buffer size (1025). (in target 'mobile' from project 'mobile')
```

Error when running from CLI:

```
2024-01-31 09:15:46.765 xcodebuild[20823:863479] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DVTDeviceFoundation.Aspect for extension Xcode.IDEiOSSupportCore.Aspect.NBDD of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiOSSupportCore
2024-01-31 09:15:46.769 xcodebuild[20823:863479] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier DVTProducts.ReleaseChannelNamer for extension DVTProducts.ReleaseChannelNamer.PV of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEDistributionSupport
2024-01-31 09:15:48.262 xcodebuild[20823:863479] [MT] DVTPlugInQuery: Requested but did not find extension point with identifier 'Xcode.DVTDeviceFoundation.CompatibleDeviceFamilyPair'. This is programmer error; code should only request extension points that are defined by itself or its dependencies.
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:285C34C7-A76F-44B1-AEFC-74D6A38DD0A3, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:285C34C7-A76F-44B1-AEFC-74D6A38DD0A3, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/lukearthur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-fxjyxyudankxxjejsdezxolszzhy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlipperKit.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FlipperPlatformWebSocket.o /Users/lukearthur/Documents/NarthurWork/taskratchet-mobile/ios/Pods/FlipperKit/iOS/FlipperKit/FlipperPlatformWebSocket.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'FlipperKit' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
]

Node.js v21.1.0
```

[The full github repo](https://github.com/TaskRatchet/taskratchet-mobile)

I have tried the following:

- Cleaning Build Folder
- Deleting DerivedData Folder
- Inspecting "Build Product Path" in project build settings (currently set to "build")
- Reinstalling all Pods
- Reinstalling xcode (both current and beta versions)
- Reinstalling xcode CLI
- Deleting my project folder and cloning fresh from my github repo

Answer (score 1):

The answer for my ended up being that the Copy Bundle Resources item in the Project > Target > Build Phases. I had ended up with the .app file itself being written to the .app file.

I ended up finding the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44255203/22929742

[image]